# My teacher wants me to disambiguate the sentence by separate tree diagrams

Tags: syntax, english

the sentence: The scared monster saw a very lovely dog with one eye.
here is what I finished so far :
to change as
 1.The scared monster with only one eye saw a very lovely dog.

and other one is that 
2.The scared monster saw a very lovely dog has only one eye.

Am i correct about this ? how can I identify the right tree  diagram?

Your kindness is a great help to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right.

(1) The scared monster saw (using one eye) a very lovely dog. 
(2) The scared monster saw a very lovely dog (who has one eye).

Normally we do not answer assignments as this goes against the policy of this website. But since you showed that you worked out half of the task, let me help you.

The adjunct which adds to ambiguity here is 'with one eye'. This adjunct is a Prepositional Phrase (a PP for short). If we adjoin PP to V' or VP it becomes a modifier of **see** (as a verb) hence it means that the *monster* has only one eye. If, however, we adjoin PP to N, or NP, it means that the *dog* (as a noun) is the one which has one eye. Did you figure it out?